# Rendering of Favorite/Ignored Tags in Firefox

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, firefox

I have spotted a bug in rendering of *Favorite Tags* and *Ignored Tags* section in Firefox.
This rendering issue is present on both *stackoverflow.com* and *meta.stackoverflow.com* sites.

I'm using Firefox 17.0.1 on Windows 7 x64.
In Google Chrome page is rendered correctly.

**Screenshots:**

***Firefox*** (please note cropped right part of both *Add* buttons)

[image]

***Chrome*** (buttons are rendered correctly)

[image]